# Utilizar contenedores de biblioteca STL con clases C++

Tags: c++, class, collection

Hola soy nuevo en la programación y estaba intentando crear un pequeño programa para probar como funcionan los contenedores de STL en las clases. El programa es solo una clase Empresa y otra Empleado, donde Empresa contiene una colección de empleados de tipo `list<Empleado*>` entre otros datos y el objetivo es poder agregar empleados a la Empresa y manipular los datos:

- ver los datos completos de los empleados
- iterarlos
- luego mi idea es agregar por ejemplo un atributo salario y sumarlos

Como para ir familiarizándome con los contenedores STL.

```
//clase Empleado.h
class Empleado{
    private:
        int nro;
        string nombre;
    public:
        Empleado(int,string);
        int getNro();
        string getNombre();
        void setNro(int);
        void setNombre(string);
};

//Empleado.cpp
Empleado :: Empleado(int nro,string nombre){
    this->nro = nro;
    this->nombre = nombre;
}
int Empleado :: getNro(){
    return nro;
}
string Empleado :: getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}
void Empleado :: setNro(int nro){
    this->nro = nro;
}
void Empleado :: setNombre(string nombre){
    this->nombre = nombre;
}

class Empresa{
    private:
        int RUT;
        string nombre;
        list<Empleado*> empleados;
    public:
        Empresa(int,string);
        int getRUT();
        string getNombre();
        list<Empleado*> getEmpleados();
        void setRUT(int);
        void setNombre(string);
        void agregarEmpleados(Empleado *);
};

//Empresa.cpp
Empresa :: Empresa (int RUT, string nombre){
    this->RUT = RUT;
    this->nombre = nombre;
}

int Empresa :: getRUT(){
    return this->RUT;
}
string Empresa :: getNombre(){
    return this->nombre;
}
list<Empleado*>   Empresa ::  getEmpleados(){
    return this->empleados;
}

void Empresa :: setRUT (int nro){
    this->RUT = nro;
}
void Empresa :: setNombre (string nombre){
    this->nombre = nombre;
}

void  Empresa :: agregarEmpleados(Empleado *e){
    empleados.push_back(e);
}

//main
int main(){
    //Creacion de empleados
    Empleado * empleado4 = new Empleado(4,"Carlos");
    Empleado * empleado1 = new Empleado(1,"Jose");
    Empleado * empleado3 = new Empleado(3,"Marcelo");
    Empleado * empleado6 = new Empleado(6,"Juan");
    Empleado * empleado5 = new Empleado(5,"Beto");
    Empleado * empleado2 = new Empleado(2,"Pepe");

    Empresa * empresa1 = new Empresa (123456, "Pobres SA");
    empresa1->agregarEmpleados(empleado1);
    empresa1->agregarEmpleados(empleado2);
    empresa1->agregarEmpleados(empleado3);

    list<Empleado*> :: iterator itr = empresa1->getEmpleados().begin();

        cout << *itr  ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Al compilar el cout *itr me arroja una dirección de memoria.

¿Es algo con el casteo? ¿Cómo se haría en este caso para que me imprima los datos del empleado?

El código tiene algun otro error?

Muchas gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 1):

> Al compilar el cout *itr me arroja una direccion de memoria.

¿Y qué esperabas? Si estás guardando direcciones de memoria en el contenedor:

```
list<Empleado*>
//           ^ <--- Lista de PUNTEROS a empleado.
```

Los punteros, guardan direcciones de memoria.

> ¿Es algo con el casteo?

No, no puede ser "*algo con el casteo*" porque no estás *casteando* nada.

> ¿Cómo se haría en este caso para que me imprima los datos del empleado?

Pues pasando el empleado al flujo de salida de datos:

```
//      v <----- Primer nivel: Sacar el contenido del iterador.
cout << **itr;
//       ^ <---- Segundo nivel: Sacar el contenido del puntero.
```

Pero esto te fallará, porque el operador de inyección de datos (`<<`) en flujo de salida carece de sobrecarga con `Empleado`, por lo que te aconsejo lo siguiente:

```
class Empleado{
    private:
        int nro;
        string nombre;
    public:
        Empleado(int,string);

        // Es una función de lectura de datos, haz que sea constante.
        int getNro() const;
        /* Es una función de lectura de datos, haz que sea constante y
           haz que devuelva una referencia (constante) para evitar copias. */
        const string &getNombre() const;

        void setNro(int);
        void setNombre(string);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Empleado &e)
{
    return o << e.getNro() << ' ' << e.getNombre();
}
```

Respecto al objeto `Empresa`, te aconsejo que construyas los `Empleado` internamente y que los guardes como instancia no como puntero:

```
class Empresa{
    private:
        int RUT;
        string nombre;
        list<Empleado> empleados;
        //   ^^^^^^^^ <--- 'Empleado' no punteros.
    public:
        Empresa(int,string);
        int getRUT();
        /* Es una función de lectura de datos, haz que sea constante y
           haz que devuelva una referencia (constante) para evitar copias- */
        string getNombre() const;
        /* Es una función de lectura de datos, haz que sea constante y
           haz que devuelva una referencia (constante) para evitar copias- */
        const list<Empleado> &getEmpleados() const;

        void setRUT(int);
        void setNombre(string);
        // Añades UN empleado, no tiene sentido que el nombre de la función sea en plural.
        void agregarEmpleado(const Empleado &);
};
```

Podrás añadir [empleados así](https://tio.run/##fVPBTuMwED3XXzHKSiWRTAXswiGNetjVXpBACMFtpZXrzmYtEtuyHS5Rvr3YiZMWSnAv9Xjem5n3Jlzrc14xWe7334TkVbNDKISyziCrN@QQq4R1G0IaK2QJktVoNeMI1u3WhHgGa@F3rStkO9US8Ecb8coc5v0lHCEdSKPWU8AX6clUvTU4hHWzrQQ/YEbKNIAFHSE2gzxwtaKjEd/aDtqOvKtWors3Ks2AK2kdtGDQNUb2XUA3pQ6vkXoZQD3jJ7ihUw/t/NBRJFgqjYY5ZYoiPcRoBI8TwBIzMigT2RQUBeBqatLfzvxvCsYm1qQ7EtigZV/o@/j89KW@4QQni7GtDWD8Z2cdCDU/M8AXOzXgvagfagVxx5s91ffQypE7r0rsgJUGS2amdTjV1rNM8JVu7P@/W8ZfUsxGu8IANRMyDTYs4liA6QWFJPEqL3D1sUr7gya/mKmUTbqZjEua3CqLs@/faXLHDMdKzabceIqGydn3a5r8RDePv6LJA@qhBbL4pwxEeVjjgjSjSPmwV0f6Z@HzzXOuGtev3ZgZNvGPPAt00ZkLv4X7/Rs):

```
Empresa e(0, "");
e.agregarEmpleado({4,"Carlos"});
e.agregarEmpleado({1,"Jose"});
e.agregarEmpleado({3,"Marcelo"});
e.agregarEmpleado({6,"Juan"});
e.agregarEmpleado({5,"Beto"});
e.agregarEmpleado({2,"Pepe"});

for (const auto &empleado : e.getEmpleados()) std::cout << empleado << '\n';
```